# how can i compare instances of timezone and datetime

Tags: python, datetime, django-3.0

i created a todo model in django with a method of clear old todo that is supposed to delete todos that were published more than 24 hours ago, i can't seem to be able to compare datetime and timezone instances in my if condition

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Todo_date = models.DateTimeField('Todo Date')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

    def create_todo(self, description, Todo_date, pub_date):
        todo = Todo(description=description,
                    Todo_date=Todo_date, pub_date=pub_date)
        todo.save()
        return todo

    def delete_todo(self, description):
        todo = Todo.objects.get(description=description)
        todo.delete()
        return "Todo removed"

    def clear_old_todo(self):
        todos = Todo.objects.all()
        time_limit = datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
        for todo in todos:
            if (timezone.now()-todo.pub_date) > (timezone.now()-time_limit):
                todo.delete()
                return "old todo cleared"
```

```
>>> Todo.clear_old_todo("self")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\projects\1stDjangoApp\ToDoList\ToDo\models.py", line 36, in clear_old_todo
    if (timezone.now()-todo.pub_date) > (timezone.now()-time_limit):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Comment: `timezone.now()-todo.pub_date` creates a *timedelta*, the difference between two times. `timezone.now()-time_limit` creates a *datetime*, since you're subtracting a `timedelta` from a `datetime`. You probably just want `timezone.now() - time_limit > todo.pub_date`…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting a `datetime` from a `datetime` gives you a `timedelta`, the difference between the two times. Subtracting a `timedelta` from a `datetime` gives you a `datetime`, a new timestamp different from the first by the amount of the `timedelta`.

In `timezone.now()-todo.pub_date`, you're subtracting two `datetime`.
In `timezone.now()-time_limit`, you're subtract a `timedelta` from a `datetime`.

You *either* want to do `timezone.now() - todo.pub_date` to produce a `timedelta` and check if that `timedelta` is `>`/`<` some specific value (i.e. compare two `timedelta`s), *or* you want to do `timezone.now() - time_limit` to produce a `datetime` in the past and check whether that is `>`/`<` your `todo.pub_date` `datetime`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, with the way i hustled i'm sure i  won't make the same mistake again. cheers mate